# Add a mysql column to a table from calculations on other tables values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables as `user_shows`, and `comments`.   They both have a key in common as `id`.

I want to have a column in `user_shows`, which will store the number of comments in the comments table when `user_shows.id = comments.id`.  I tried, and came up with something like:

```
ALTER TABLE user_shows 
ADD num_comments INT(4) AS (SELECT id 
                              FROM comments, 
                                   user_shows 
                             WHERE comments.id = user_shows.id)
```

...but this didn't work.

Comment: Adding a column, and populating it are separate things -- which means separate queries

Comment: Thanks to clear my queries OMG Ponies, I just thought that there must be something that did both simultaneously :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to write two separate queries like this:-

```
ALTER TABLE user_shows 
ADD num_comments INT(4);

UPDATE user_shows SET num_comments = (SELECT count(id) FROM comments WHERE comments.id = user_shows.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion for you is create [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) of for this purpose.

Something like below:

```
create view user_shows_comments  as (

   SELECT u.*,count(c.id) as num_comments
   FROM user_shows  as u left join comments as c on u.id=c.user_id
   group  by c.user_id
)
```

Use this view for further queries. It will be updated automatically with tables.